# Web Scraping is giving wrong/empty output

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pracuj_base_url = 'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca?pn=2'

page = requests.get(pracuj_base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

job_elems = soup.find_all('li', class_='results__list-container-item')

for job_elem in job_elems:
  title_elem = job_elem.find('a', class_='offer-details__title-link')
  print(title_elem.text)
```

Why this code is giving me only 10 results the rest is "None".
I inspected the website and each

with this class_='results__list-container-item' has exactly the same structure. Any ideas. As the final result I want:

- Title of the position
- Link to this job
- Company name
- Location (ie: Katowice)
- Type of the agreement (place: below location ie: "Umowa o prace")
- Period for the agreement (to the right of agreement's type, ie: "Pelny etat")
- For whom is this offer (to the right of the period, ie: "Specjalista")
- Date of publication

On the other hand:

```
print(len(job_elems))
```

Is returning proper value: 50 jobs listed on that page.

As I am trying:

```
print(job_elems[34])
```

The outcome is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the website loads the first 10 jobs and you can see them if you viewed the source code but the rest are being generated and injected to the dom via JavaScript so you will only see them after the browser render them but not in the source code .

[image]

But the whole 50 results lives within a javascript tag as a json object

```
import re , json , requests

pracuj_base_url = 'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca?pn=2'

page = requests.get(pracuj_base_url)
match = re.search(r'INITIAL_STATE__\s*= (.*?)};',page.text)
data = match.group(1) + '}'
jobs = json.loads(data)['offers']

for index , job in enumerate(jobs,1):
        print(f'{index } / {len(jobs)}')
        print(job)
```

Output will be a dictionary as follows :

```
50 / 50
{'commonOfferId': '23400166', 'jobTitle': 'Inżynier Procesów Logistycznych', 'employer': 'XPO Supply Chain Poland Sp. z o.o. ', 'companyProfileUrl': 'https://pracodawcy.pracuj.pl/company/20012541/profile', 'companyId': 20012541, 'logo': 'https://i.gpcdn.pl/oferty-loga-firm/wyniki-wyszukiwania/16595.png', 'lastPublicated': '2020-04-04T17:00:00', 'expirationDate': '2020-05-14T00:00:00', 'salary': '', 'employmentLevel': 'Specjalista', 'jobDescription': ' Do Twoich zadań będzie należeć: Współodpowiedzialność za rozwój sprzedaży usług logistyki kontraktowej Kalkulacja projektów logistycznych w oparciu o dostępne narzędzia Opracowywanie wdrożenia oraz budowanie procesów dla nowych klientów...', 'offerType': [], 'optionalCv': False, 'countryName': 'Polska', 'mainCategoriesIds': [5017, 5028], 'offers': [{'offerId': 7439566, 'offerUrl': 'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/inzynier-procesow-logistycznych-warszawa,oferta,7439566', 'regionName': 'mazowieckie', 'cities': ['Warszawa'], 'label': 'Warszawa'}], 'typesOfContract': ['Umowa o pracę'], 'workSchedules': ['Pełny etat'], 'remoteWork': False}
```